# Purpose of assigning a value to the Angular template element reference?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I noticed that some devs assign a value to their element reference like this:

```
#searchInput="matInput"
```

And this has the effect of turning off autocomplete for the field.  Is that why it's done?

This is a more complete example:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
  <input matInput #searchInput="matInput" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

[This article has more context](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/angular-material-dynamic-suffix-icon-color-change-2e6e1059abd6).  It uses the `#searchInput` in a declarative way only.  It will work without assigning a value to `#searchInput` which made me curious about why people do assign a value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it' completely unrelated.

This syntax is used to get the Angular component as a view child of your current component.

In the source code, it's defined in the `@Component` decorator as `exportAs`.

[(See it on their repo)](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/input/input.ts#L69)

It allows a component to declare a variable as a material input, and control it programmatically.

To turn the autocomplete off, this is totally different. Since I'm not sure if you are asking for that of for someone to explain the syntax, I'll simply stop there and wait for you to comment my answer, in case you need it !

Comment: So is `matInput` effectively the Type of the `#searchInput` reference?  So for example if we were to use `@ViewChild` to grab the field with type `MatInput` this will pass Typechecking because the `#searchInput` directive is set to `matInput` ?

Comment: I added an article I wrote to the bottom of the question for more context.

Comment: No, it depends on how you declare your view child. You can either read the material class, or the HTML element. But yes, if you read the custom class, it will be of type material input. But there is no type checking in templates, so I'm not sure about your question ?

Comment: Does the assignment of `matInput` to `#searchInput` actually buy us anything functionality wise?  AFAIK even if we don't assign the value, we still get to reference `#searchInput` in the template and we can inject the property into our class with `@ViewChild` etc.?

Comment: Yes it does, since it gives you control over the input programmatically. For instance, you could force the error label to pop out even though the input has no error (useless but shows the capability). And without the matInput, you would have a reference to the element itself : if it's the input, it's just a html input, not the actual material input.

Comment: OK - I think I see what you are saying now.   So for example: `@ViewChild('title') 
private elTitle : ElementRef;`   The title element reference is declared like this `#title`.  And since we don't assign `#title=matInput` we get and `ElementRef` with `@ViewChild` and not a `MatInput`?

Comment: Exactly, but that in the template too ! If, in your template, you use the `title` reference, it will point to the `nativeElement` and not the material input (by the way, it's `@ViewChild('title', {read: MatInput }) title: MatInput` to get the material input as a view child)

Comment: Aha!!!  Very cool - Thank you so much for all the elaboration!  You ROCK!!